# Permissions in IIS7/ASP.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

Hope someone can assist with this one, I'm about ready to pull out what little hair I have left..

Anyway, I have an ASP.net WebForms/MVC3 intranet site running with Windows Authentication, but I have one user who is getting prompted for his username/password when trying to view one of the MVC pages.

The page URL is `/FM`, which routes to the area (FM), and renders the default route (`/FM/Home/Index`).  If the user uses the /FM url, it prompts for a password and returns a 403 even if it's entered correctly, but if he uses the (`/FM/Home/Index`) path, it returns the page without issue.

It's only been a problem with this one user account, and I've had him try it with different browsers, different machines, etc., with no change.  The odd thing is, it's only his account, and it works just fine for other users with the exact same AD permissions as him.

The one error I've been able to find is this in the event log:

```
Event code: 4008 
Event message: File authorization failed for the request. 
Event time: 6/18/2012 3:19:33 PM 
Event time (UTC): 6/18/2012 7:19:33 PM 
Event ID: 65994829b06b4aa4a92d71b8e985ec24 
Event sequence: 4217 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-3-129845173218765349 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: [Root application path] 
    Machine name: [WebserverName] 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 9776 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: [IIS APPPOOL\WebsiteName]

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://mydomain/FM/ 
    Request path: /FM/ 
    User host address: [User Host Address]
    User: [Domain\Username]
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: [IIS APPPOOL\WebsiteName]
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do the users have roaming profiles? And are all the users using IE to access this site?

Comment: No romaing profiles, and all the other users are using either IE7, Chrome, or Firefox.

Comment: That kills my theory then, IE has some settings that can mess up automatic login. The logical conclusion then is that this user must not have exactly the same settings as all other users, or alternatively this user has somehow explicitly been excluded. How are you controlling access exactly, IIS settings, web.config, Authorize attributes?

Comment: IIS Settings.  I have a few Authorize attributes controlling access to other parts of the site, but not any part of this section.  I'm thinking I'm going to have the user's account deleted/recreated to see if it helps. I just can't get past why it wouldn't work with one route (/FM), but works just fine using the explicit route (/FM/Home/Index), considering that they route to the exact same action method.  Thanks!

Comment: It is pretty bizarre. The only other thing I could suggest is getting fiddler or wireshark or something like that and looking at the requests going over and back and see if there's anything useful there. But hopefully recreating the user will help.